# How to purge a Plone site completely of LinguaPlone

Tags: plone, linguaplone

We set up a LinguaPlone site several years ago and the translation facilities were largely unused. Overtime it has gone through a series of migrations and upgrades and we are now running on Plone 4.3.3.

During recent migration, a lot of our migration issues were tied linked back to  "KeyError, no language set" type errors.

At this point we'd like to purge the site of LinguaPlone and get to a clean catalog.

We've tried removing LinguaPlone, upgrading to plone.app.multilingual but at this point we just want a clean catalog purged of any LinguaPlone related things.

How does one go about completely removing the vestiges of LinguaPlone from a Plone 4.3.3 site?

Comment: Please, try to provide one of these exceptions here.

PS: if you don't want to use translation facility, just focus on removing LinguaPlone. Adding another translation add-on like p.a.multilingual will simply add new complexity to your Plone site.